# Jquery UI Autocomplete empty $_REQUEST parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a form

```
<div class='row' >
    <div class='large-12 columns search_bar'>
        <div class='row'>
            <form action='search.php'>
                <div class='large-8 large-offset-2 medium-8 columns search_home'><input type='text' id='search'></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And am calling the autocomplete from jQuery UI like:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(function() {
        $("search").autocomplete({ 
            source: "search_retailers.php",     // provide the name of the PHP source file here
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

`search.php` is formatted like this:

```
include ("dbinfo.php");
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];

$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);    
}
echo json_encode ($results);
```

The process is 'working' in that I get the JSON back but I get all results, upon further investigation, `$_REQUEST['search']` is blank, any ideas what I'm missing please?

Thanks,

Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the typed data it's `term` not `search`, try:

```
include ("dbinfo.php");
$search = $_REQUEST['term'];

$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);    
}
echo json_encode ($results);
```

and you are missing a # to reference you element id for `#search`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete({ 
        source: "search_retailers.php",     // provide the name of the PHP source file here
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why would it be $_REQUEST['term'] when the ID of the input is 'search' on the form?  I will check when I get home